# textmates' c++ keywords in color

Tags: macos, textmate

I was wondering how to enable multi-color function in textmate to display keywords (c-like syntax) in color?

So, for example in sublime, pressing CTRL+SHIFT+P will pop-up a menu from which a user can choose the coloring pattern for the code.

Answer (score 0):

Just save the file with a file extension for the programming language you are using, such as .c for c and the syntax highlighting will appear.

Comment: yeah, but sometimes I use different extensions - like .y and .lex, which have plain black letters. Even though its not c, having c-syntax is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the window there is a drop down menu that shows all of the different styles and contexts that you can use. [image: Point and click]